# alertbox receiver sms android does not appear

Tags: android, sms, android-alertdialog

I'm creating applications using alertbox sms on receiving his sms.
But I have trouble because the alertbox code does not appear when the sms is received.

My code:

```
//SMSReceiver

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {       
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, SMSNotif.class);
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(startIntent);
    }
}
//SMSNotif


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class SMSNotif extends Activity 
{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;
static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
    this.registerReceiver(registerReceiver, filter);
}
private void displayAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
            false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
private final BroadcastReceiver registerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
        {
            //your SMS processing code
            displayAlert();
        }
    }
};
}
```

If the program does not run out alertbox, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For showing AlertDialog when sms is recived change your code as:

**STEP 1:**

Register an Reciver for incoming SMS notifaction as in `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
  <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and SMS_RECEIVED permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

---

**STEP 2:** 
Change your `SMSReceiver.java` as:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
               String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
        {
            //Start Activity here
             Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, SMSNotif.class);
                     startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                     context.startActivity(startIntent);
        }    
    }
}
```

---

**STEP 3:**
Change your `SMSNotif.java` Activity code as:

```
public class SMSNotif extends Activity 
{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.Activity_layout);
     // call displayAlert() here
       displayAlert();
}
    private void displayAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(
            false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
     }

}
```

---

Comment: thanks for her advice
but the code is still the same result
alertbox still not out when sms received
is there any input else??
please help me pretty hard about this